# Apache shiro + kerberos authentication

Tags: java, authentication, kerberos, shiro

I am working on a web application which is rest client and uses rest services(APIs) to perform any action. I have integrated apache shiro to perform authentication using jdbc realm which is working fine.

Now I am looking for a solution to perform authentication using apacheDS LDAP. I am planning to use kerberos authentication, but I got no luck to find any useful article or example to implement kerberos authentication using apache shiro.

I found apache shiro's official web site having support of kerberos.

https://shiro.apache.org/authorization-features.html

But I found no realm which can directly be used or provide me enough information to implement custom realm for kerberos authentication.

Please provide me a way to implement this or if not possible with kerberos then any other solutions for SSO(Single Sign On) which is capable enough to provide security implementation for my web application.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, one year later, I am in the same boat. Shiro with kerberos is the requirement. Were you able to find anything useful or implement any example I can look up to? That would be a massive help. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see from [comments elsewhere](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SHIRO-499?focusedCommentId=15866476&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-15866476), and the associated change to the Shiro documentation you linked, there is as yet no official Shiro Kerberos realm. I, too, have been searching for ideas on this topic, and I recently came across [Apache Aurora's version](https://github.com/apache/aurora/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/aurora/scheduler/http/api/security/Kerberos5Realm.java), which seems like a good starting point.